# DFA that recognizes 0 in every odd position

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I had a question that asked for the DFA that accepts the following language:

```
{w | every odd position of w is a 0 }
```

Should this DFA accept the empty string, since it doesn't have an odd position?

Comment: "Should this DFA accept the empty string, since it doesn't have an odd position?" - Yes. The condition vacuously holds.

Comment: $\forall x \in \emptyset : P(x)$ holds for all predicates $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since $|\epsilon| = 0$, there are no odd positions; therefore, that DFA would accept $\epsilon$.